# Обновление JTable при клике на листке JTree

Tags: jtable, java, swing

Я столкнулся с проблемой при обновлении содержимого JTable при нажатии на листок JTree. Таблица заполняется лишь в первый раз, в следующие разы при нажатии на другой лист дерева содержимое таблицы исчезает. Помогите, в чем может проблема?

```
DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
tree1.setModel(treeModel);
tree1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);                        
tree1.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

@Override
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
   DefaultMutableTreeNode node = 
              (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree1.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

    Object nodeInfo = node.getUserObject();
         if (nodeInfo instanceof Groups) {
            Groups group = (Groups)nodeInfo;
            System.out.println(group.getGroupName());
            loadStudents(group);
            } 
          if (nodeInfo instanceof YearOfEducation) {
                YearOfEducation year = (YearOfEducation)nodeInfo;
                System.out.println(year.getNumberOfYear());
            } else return;
          }
        });
```

Метод loadStudents:

```
protected void loadStudents(Groups group) {
try {
    final List<Students> stud = ari.getStudentsFromGroup(group.getGroupid());
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            tableStudents.setModel(new StudentTableModel(stud));

        }
    });
    //updateProgress(stud);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

StudentTableModel class:

```
public class StudentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

 private List<Students> students = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Students>());

public StudentTableModel(List<Students> students) {
if(students.iterator().hasNext()) 
this.students = students;
}

 public int getRowCount() {
  if (students != null) {
    return students.size();
  }
  return 0;
 }

public int getColumnCount() {
return 20; 
 }

  public Students getRow(int row){
      return (Students) students.get(row);
  }

public String getColumnName(int column) {
String[] colNames = {"Отметка о сдаче внутр. экз", "Группа №", "Фамилия", "Имя", "Отчество", "Пол",
        "Дата рождения","Место рождения","Адрес", "Тип документа","Серия документа","Номер документа","Дата выдачи",
        "Кем выдано","Образование","Образовательное учреждение","Место работы","Телефон",
        "Дата сдачи внутр. экзамена","Отметка об отчислении"};

return colNames[column];
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (students != null) {

    Students bt = (Students) students.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0: 
            return bt.getEkzFlag();
        case 1:
            return bt.getGroups().getGroupName();
        case 2: 
            return bt.getSurname();
        case 3:
            return bt.getName();
        case 4:
            return bt.getPatronymicname();
        case 5:
            return bt.getPol();
        case 6:
            return bt.getDatebirth();
        case 7:
            return bt.getBirthplace();
        case 8:
            return bt.getAddress();
        case 9:
            return bt.getTypeDocum();
        case 10:
            return bt.getDocseries();
        case 11:
            return bt.getDocnumber();
        case 12:
            return bt.getDocdate();
        case 13:
            return bt.getDoinfo();
        case 14:
            return bt.getTypeEducation().getName();
        case 15:
            return bt.getEducationinfo();
        case 16:
            return bt.getJobplace();
        case 17:
            return bt.getPhone();
        case 18:
            return bt.getEkzData();
        case 19:
            return bt.getOtchislen();
    }
}
return null;
}

public void setValueAt(Students aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
if (students != null) {
    // Получаем из вектора ставку
    Students bt = (Students) students.get(rowIndex);
    // В зависимости от колонки возвращаем 
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0: 
             bt.setEkzFlag(aValue.getEkzFlag());
        case 1:
             bt.setGroups(aValue.getGroups());
        case 2: 
             bt.setSurname(aValue.getSurname());
        case 3:
             bt.setName(aValue.getName());
        case 4:
             bt.setPatronymicname(aValue.getPatronymicname());
        case 5:
             bt.setPol(aValue.getPol());
        case 6:
             bt.setDatebirth(aValue.getDatebirth());
        case 7:
             bt.setBirthplace(aValue.getBirthplace());
        case 8:
             bt.setAddress(aValue.getAddress());
        case 9:
            bt.setTypeDocum(aValue.getTypeDocum());
        case 10:
             bt.setDocseries(aValue.getDocseries());
        case 11: 
             bt.setDocnumber(aValue.getDocnumber());
        case 12:
             bt.setDocdate(aValue.getDocdate());
        case 13:
             bt.setDoinfo(aValue.getDoinfo());
        case 14:
             bt.setTypeEducation(aValue.getTypeEducation());
        case 15:
             bt.setEducationinfo(aValue.getEducationinfo());
        case 16:
             bt.setJobplace(aValue.getJobplace());
        case 17:
             bt.setPhone(aValue.getPhone());
        case 18:
            bt.setEkzData(aValue.getEkzData());
        case 19:
            bt.setOtchislen(aValue.getOtchislen());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Про таблицу - после добавления элементов в табличку сделай вызов fireDataChanged(), если я не ошибся с написанием, он относится к модели таблицы - должно помочь. И есть мнение, что ты меняешь всю модель таблицы в коде. Причина может крыться в этом. Попробуй не задавать новый объект модели, а менять данные в уже существующей. Зачистил таблицу - добавил новые данные при изменении выбора листа дерева